Does iOS have a capability to store data locally on the device in a way it requires Face ID to access it?
Within the mobile app for Apple iOS I'd like to store some data, say a simple string, locally on the device so the data is available only for the same app. Furthermore access to the data requires user to be present and authenticated with Face ID for each time my app attends to read the data.
Does the platform offer such capability? If so, how to use it? Otherwise, what are the capabilities I could use to implement the requirements?

Yes ios offers keychain service to store some data and authentication like face id. you can combine these together to do what you want.
